# projects.getiampolicy (cloudresource manager api)

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Utilizing the cloud resource api, specifically projects.getIamPolicy Running this for projects I own returns the following:

> "error": {   "code": 403,   "message": "The caller does not have
>   permission",   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED

I have enabled the Cloud Resource Manager API with no success. I can successfully run the gcloud sdk command "projects get-iam-policy projectID" however the API errors out in the API Explorer as well as via Python.

Any help?

Comment: The user you are authenticated with does not have access to projects.getIamPolicy Without seeing your code It will be hard for anyone to tell you what is wrong with it.  make sure you have authencated with the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo on the API explorer page I am utilizing oAuth as the myself, who is the project owner. Other getiampolicy methods work (ie Organizations) however this one is erroring out.

Comment: Issue solved. Apparently the issue is (as of 2/11/17) due to incorrect documentation from Google regarding this API. Documentation calls out formatting the request with _'projects/{project}'_ 

However, the correct format is to only specify the project id or project name only.